# Cannot prevent CardView in RecyclerView to clip childs

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-xml, android-cardview, clipping

I'm trying to move an ImageView slightly out of the cardView, but the cardview keeps clipping the child.

I have following XML structure:

```
<RecyclerView>
    <CardView>
         <LinearLayout>
              <LinearLayout>
                   <ImageView/>
                   ...
```

I have set all containers with:

```
clipToPadding="false"
clipChildren="false"
```

And everything besides the RecyclerView got `setClipToOutline="false"`.

On top the cardView has `cardUseCompatPadding="true"`

Android Studio predicts the following:
[Screenshot out of Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Ab8.png) (SO prevents the image, since I'm new here with little reputation..)

But for whatever reason on my phone (Galaxy A3, Lineage OS, Android 9) the image view is still clipped.

Any idea how I can get the desired behavior not only in Android Studio but also on my phone?

---

UPDATE

card_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:cardView="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <variable name="..."
        type="..."/>
</data>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    cardView:setClipToOutline="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        cardView:setClipToOutline="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            cardView:setClipToOutline="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card_view_flag"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:translationY="-10dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                cardView:setClipToOutline="false"
                android:src="@drawable/colored_flag"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <CheckBox
                style="?android:attr/starStyle"
                android:scaleX="1.5"
                android:scaleY="1.5"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

recyclerview..

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:paddingBottom="70dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Comment: show your complete layout

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem here you go

Comment: You should use a ConstraintLayout in this case. it would solve your problem.

Comment: Where? Instead of what?
I do not foresee to change cardview.

Comment: inside the cardview, instead of the parent LinearLayout

Comment: Excuse me, i misunderstood what you want. Now i edited my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is put the image outside the cardView

```
<ConstraintLayout>
    <CardView>
    <ImageView/>
```

Comment: Yes, it still is inside your main `layout` tag

Comment: Well, thanks, this lead me into the correct direction.
(to not have to modify the source code..) I ended up doing it like this: 

<CardView>
    <ConstraintLayout>
        <CardView>
        <ImageView/>

The outer card is transparent and gives the larger frame. The Image can now sit outside the inner card.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a well formatted full result of what @Sinner was leading me to...

Since my ViewHolder is inflated like this:

```
@Override
public ListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                       int viewType)
{
    CardView v = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_card, parent, false);

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}
```

And I use CardView all the way downstream, I modified @Sinners answer like this to make it work:

```
<CardView>
    <ConstraintLayout>
        <CardView>
        <ImageView/>
```

With the outer CardView being transparent, the ConstrainLayout having a padding and `clipToPadding="false"`. Then the ImageView could sit outside of the inner CardView and look as supposed :)

Thanks!

Comment: The parent CardView serves no real purpose other than to slow down your UI performance. You should remove it.